# Why do i get this error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_widget' when im trying to remove Target widget?

Tags: python, kivy

Why do i get this error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_widget' when im trying to remove Target widget?

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '800')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '600')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.config import Config
import random, time

from kivy.animation import Animation

from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty

from kivy.core.window import Window

import random



a = Builder.load_string('''

<BattleField>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'


<Target>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1 #red
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
''')


class BattleField(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BattleField, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        appear_time = random.randint(2,4)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.appear_target, 1)


    def appear_target(self, *args):

        c = Target(pos=(700,0))
        self.add_widget(c)


class Target(Widget):

    velocity_x = NumericProperty(-10)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Target, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1/60.)

    def update(self, *args):

        self.x += self.velocity_x #velocity[0]
        self.y += self.velocity_y #velocity[1]


        if self.x < 0:
            self.parent.remove_widget(self)



class ClockApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return BattleField()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ClockApp().run()
```

I want to remove the Target widget which is a red rectangle
when it moves out of the window, but this part cause the error
i dont know why.

```
if self.x < 0:
   self.parent.remove_widget(self)
```

Please help me. Advanced thank you.

Comment: if you get an error about NoneType it means the `self.parent` is empty. how are you instancing your `target` widget ?

Comment: I really do not know kivy at all; but the error you are getting means that you are trying to call method remove_widget() on an object of type None. This is of course not what you want. In your case, this means that self.parent is actually None.

Who is responsible for initializing self.parent?

Comment: I'm referring to the parent class BattleField, isn't it? Please i need help. Even i make it: 
self.remove_widget(self)
it doesnt work properly. Could you modify my code? I just want to remove the Target widget once it is out of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm referring to the parent class BattleField, isn't it

No, it isn't. You are refering to the "parent" attribute of the current "Target" instance, which - from the error you get - is obviously `None` at this moment. It *might* be **an instance of** your `BattleField` class at some point, but it could be anything else too.

[From the doc](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=widget#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.parent) (emphasis is mine):

> The parent of a widget is set when the widget is added to another widget **and unset when the widget is removed from its parent**.

So what is most probably happening is that `Target.update()` is still being called *after* a first call to `self.parent.remove_widget()`, so at this point it doesn't have a parent anymore. You can easily test it:

```
    if self.x < 0:
        if self.parent:
            # would be better to use the `logging` module
            print("removing target {} from parent {}".format(self, self.parent))
            self.parent.remove_widget(self)
        else:
            print("target {} already removed from parent ?".format(self))
```

But note that the mere fact that `Target.update` is still being called at this point might be a indication of something else being wrong with your code... I don't know kivi and even less your app so I can't tell but you may not be doing things the right way and you might have some memory leak here.

Answer (score 0):

## AttributeError

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_widget'

## Cause

The AttributeError occurred during the second time while trying to `remove_widget` because the widget/Target instance no longer has a parent, and `Clock.schedule_interval` is still active for that widget/Target instance.

## Note

The first time when self.x is less than 0, the widget/Target instance was removed successfully.

## Solution

You need to [unschedule](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#unscheduling) the event using `Clock.unschedule(self.event)`.

## Snippets

```
class Target(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(-10)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Target, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1 / 60.)

    def update(self, *args):
        self.x += self.velocity_x  # velocity[0]
        self.y += self.velocity_y  # velocity[1]

        if self.x < 0:
            Clock.unschedule(self.event)
            self.parent.remove_widget(self)
```